# Beginning storyboard in XAML in wp7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, storyboard

I have an application in windows phone 7 where I require to have images' opacity change from 0 to 1 gradually on loading the application. I thought of using storyboard but I have to begin each and every storyboard on page loaded. 
This becomes a problem whenever I have many storyboards. How can i indicate it in the XAML itself that I need to begin the storyboard? Also How can I bind multiple items to a common storyboard?

Comment: How do you have your object tree organized? For example if you have all these elements in the same panel (Grid, StackPanel, Canvas, or whatever) you could apply the transition to the parent container instead of each individually. Which would allow for one Storyboard you could fire off with the loaded event of the view.

Comment: its like i have images in different panels (panels which also contain other information, which i don't want to animate), all these panels are in a listbox.

Comment: Can you share an abridged of your template?